# Yocto Image file size reduces after adding a particular package

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, yocto, bitbake

I built a core-image-sato image with the following configuration:

```
MACHINE = "intel-core2-32"
```

The generated image size is nearly 1.2 GB.

After i add "x11vnc" package, the size is reduced to 380 MB. This image doesn't boot successfully on the hardware.

Why is the image size reduced instead of increasing

How can we debug what is going wrong?

Comment: IMHO, the best way to find out is using buildhistory.  @see: https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/latest/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#enabling-and-disabling-build-history .  When enabled, you can use the 'buildhistory-diff -a' command to see the difference between builds done.  Note: you have to be in your build directory to run this command.

Comment: How did you enabled it?  And did you first run the bitbake without x11vnc then a build with the modification?  Only one build doesn't give a difference.  BTW, there should be a buildhistory directory under your build directory when it is enabled.

Comment: I got buildhistory working, but i see lot of files especially kernel modules are being removed after we add x11vnc

Comment: Looking at the rootfs lot of packages have been removed, for example init is also not being present. Why adding a package removes all these other packages

Comment: I'm fairly certain there's a mistake in how you added your package, so please explain exactly what you did to add x11vnc to the image.

Comment: IMAGE_INSTALL += " x11vnc"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The core-image-sato image you use inherits core-image.bbclass, which sets a default value of IMAGE_INSTALL using the ?= operator.

This means that if you try to extend IMAGE_INSTALL by using the += operator from somewhere that is evaluated before the default value is set using the ?= operator, the default values will never be added. So instead of adding x11vnc which was the intention, it ended up as the only content of IMAGE_INSTALL which renders the image unbootable and incomplete.

Use IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " x11vnc " and it should work just fine.

You can read the details of the different operators in the [bitbake manual](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/latest/bitbake-user-manual/bitbake-user-manual.html#setting-a-default-value).